# How to check IEEE754 overflow range

Tags: ieee-754

consider multipling 2 floating point numbers a and b
Let say expA=127, expB = 10
multplying significands give 1.101 x 2^137
so 137 >= 127 >= -126 so there is overflow

 if -126 >= resultExp so there is underflow

here I am not sure how to get 127 and -126
127 (because 01111111?)
-126 (because 10000010?) why not 10000000

what if exp is 5 bit? 01111 >= x >= 10010 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exponent section in floating point, at least in IEEE 754, is not represented in 2's complement as you mentioned, it is represented as follows:

Let us assume that the exponent section is of width n:

1. All zeroes, 000...000, i.e. Zero, represent denormals as well as +ve or -ve Zeroes in floating point.
2. The next representation, 000...001, i.e. One represents the least possible exponent, i.e. -126 in single-precision, that means that 0000...010 represents -125, 000...011 represents -124 and son on.
3. 111...110 represents the maximum exponent, i.e. 127 in single-precision.
4. 111...111 represents overflow and NaN representations.

Comment: so if exp(n bits) not all 0/1, exp represents exp-111...111(n-1 bits) ?

Comment: If it is not all 0's or 1's, the exponent equals `Unsigned representation within n bits - (2^(n-1) - 1 )`. That is you have a bias of `2^(n-1) -1` where `n` is the width of the exponent section.

Answer (score 0):

see this: [IEEE-754 specs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985)

- so you know what bits to extract
- this C++ code should work

  ```
  int e;
  float f=1.5e+34;
  unsigned int u;
  u=((unsigned int*)((void*)(&f)))[0];
  e=(u>>23)&&255;
       if (e==255);       // +/-Inf,NaN...
  else if (e==0) e-=128; // denormalized
  else e-=127;            // normalized
  ```
- in e is exponent of float f
- also do not forget that the mantisa's multiplication can lower the result's exponent by 1
- and for denormalized numbers even more

So the solution for `a*b=c` is:

1. set a0 as a but set its exponent to 0
2. set b0 as b but set its exponent to 0
3. compute `c0=a0*b0`
4. compute the result exponent
5. add the c0's exponent change to it
6. now you can test for over/underflow safely